# Why line fit is not drawn?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to plot a simple line fit using sklearn linear regression. Unfortunately, for some reason, the line fit itself is not drawn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    #loading file
    arr = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", dtype=float, delimiter=";", names=True)

    #voltage
    X = np.array([[i[0] for i in arr]])
    print("Voltage")
    print(X)

    #left wheel
    LEFT_Y = np.array([[i[1] for i in arr]])
    print("Left wheel")
    print(LEFT_Y)

    #right wheel
    RIGHT_Y = np.array([[i[2] for i in arr]])
    print("Right wheel")
    print(RIGHT_Y)

    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, LEFT_Y)

    plt.scatter(X, LEFT_Y, color='blue')
    plt.plot(X, model.predict(X), color='red')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: so what's the model.x after fitting?

Comment: @UlisesBussi, what do you mean?

Comment: shorter `X = np.array([arr[:,0]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in creating incorrect NumPy arrays.
They have to be created this way:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in arr]) #no second braket
```

The same for other arrays.

Comment: you have the same code in question - where is difference?